# equation for non-axis-crossing linear function

Tags: c, math, linear-algebra

I want to print out a line, which's points are given by the user. I use this to check if a point is on the line. (I know it can be done more efficent. Dont worry about that.)

```
int proportionalFactor = (x2 - x1) / (y2 - y1);
int offset = y1 - x1 * proportionalFactor;

for(int y = 0; y < 100; y++){                         //going over
   for(int x = 0; x < 100; x++){                      //every point
      if(y == proportionalFactor * x + offset){       //and checking if it's on the line
         printf("X");                                 //if so, mark it
      }else{
         printf(" ");                                 //if not, skip it
      }
   }
}
```

As you can see, I just use the normal equation for a linear function. But in two cases this does not work. Either the line is horizontal, or vertical. For every even slightly diagonal line it works. Here are pictures of how it looks in the program if that helps:

With input: 10|10, 90|90 - works fine
[image: With input: 10|10, 90|90]

With input: 10|10, 10|90 - as you can see it's horizontal, although it should be vertical
[image: With input: 10|10, 10|90]

Aaaand last but not least with input: 10|10, 10|90 - should be vertical line

The program crashes when I enter these values, so no picture for that case

My question is, if I can change anything in my equation to make this work and what part of the equation I interpreted wrong?

Comment: That is an assignment: `if(y = ....` It is not checking anything. A good compiler with warnings enabled should print some message to indicate that.

Comment: oh you are right. in the original code of my program i wrote this corectly, so thats not the issue. i edited it

Comment: That is exactly the reason why you are supposed to provide the code that you actually compiled and that shows the problem. Not some made up impersonator code that is just good enough to annoy readers

Comment: Please provide complete code as a [mre].

Comment: Why would you think the “proportionalFactor” is an integer? If `x2 - x1` is not a multiple of `y2 - y1`, then `(x2 - x1) / (y2 - y1)` will lose the fractional part of the quotient.

Comment: it would be way more complicated and would take things in acount that don't matter

Comment: Please read the link. Not asking for a full dump. In fact please don't. The requirement is for a *minimal* and *complete* example. The link explains why that is so important and what that means in more detail.

Comment: Also, if the “proportionalFactor” is a difference in x coordinates divided by a difference in y coordinates, then multiplying it by an x coordinate, as in `x1 * proportionalFactor` is wrong. Make sure the math works by hand before putting it into code.

Comment: well thats why im asking the question. tell me what the right equation is

Comment: We usually write slopes as y distances divided by x distances. So the general equation for a line containing points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) is y−y1 = (y2−y1)/(x2−x1) • (x−x1). To avoid division, we multiply that by (x2−x1), which gives (y−y1)•(x2−x1) = (y2−y1)•(x−x1), which is an equation you can test in C even with integer coordinates, as long as the arithmetic does not overflow the range of the integer type used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a line contains the points (*x*<sub>1</sub>, *y*<sub>1</sub>) and (*x*<sub>2</sub>, *y*<sub>2</sub>), an equation for the line is (*y*−*y*<sub>1</sub>) / (*x*−*x*<sub>1</sub>) = (*y*<sub>2</sub>−*y*<sub>1</sub>) / (*x*<sub>2</sub>−*x*<sub>1</sub>). Intuitively, this says the slope of the segment from (*x*<sub>1</sub>, *y*<sub>1</sub>) to a point (*x*, *y*) is the same as the slope of a segment from (*x*<sub>1</sub>, *y*<sub>1</sub>) to (*x*<sub>2</sub>, *y*<sub>2</sub>).

However, the expressions in the equation are not defined when there are divisions by zero, which occur when the line is vertical, so *x*<sub>1</sub> = *x*<sub>2</sub>, or when *x* is *x*<sub>1</sub>. To correct this, we can multiply by (*x*−*x*<sub>1</sub>) and by (*x*<sub>2</sub>−*x*<sub>1</sub>). This gives us (*y*−*y*<sub>1</sub>) • (*x*<sub>2</sub>−*x*<sub>1</sub>) = (*y*<sub>2</sub>−*y*<sub>1</sub>) • (*x*−*x*<sub>1</sub>). That is also beneficial because avoiding division means we can use integer arithmetic, if all the variables involved are integers.

Thus, provided no integer overflow occurs in the arithmetic, a point (`x`, `y`) is on the line defined by (`x1`, `y1`) and (`x2`, `y2`) if and only if `(y-y1) * (x2-x2) == (y2-y1) * (x-x1)`.